# Problem with updating the css file used in my Django project

Tags: css, django

I am creating my first Django project and I want to create a css stylesheet for my project. The css file that I want to use is `/static/css/main.css`. I load the static file in my `base.html` template using:

```
{% load static %}
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
</head>
```

The problem is that when I edit and save the `main.css` file, no change is visible on any of the webpages. When I checked the url `127.0.0.0:8000/static/css/main.css`, it shows the css file, but only the old version before I edited it. I tried restarting both the development server and my virtualenv and making sure that I have saved the changes, but neither resolved the issue. When I viewed the page source code and clicked on the link to the css stylesheet, it still showed the old version on the url `127.0.0.0:8000/static/css/main.css`.

When I add styling inside the `<style></style>` tags, it works just fine.

How do I make it so that it shows the new version of the css file?

Answer (score 1):

your problem may be caused by the browser using a cached version of your css file. try disabling cache in firefox inspectelements > storage > cacheStorage.

if it persists try loading the page in incognito mode

Comment: if it solved you problem. please make it your recommended answer